# Tunneling Using Plink: Command Line Option for "Local ports accept connections from other hosts"

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, putty, plink

I am trying to forward port from A:1234 to B:5678. Now, C will connect to A:1234 and will get forwarded to B:5678.

I could get this to work using PuTTY using this configuration:
[PuTTY Tunnels Configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNNiR.png)

Now, I am trying to do the same using plink. Unfortunately, I don't know what option should I use with plink that would be equivalent to "Local ports accept connections from other hosts" in the screenshot. The command I tried is

```
plink -i dummy.ppk -L *:5678:localhost:1234 account@12.34.56.78
```

What would be the plink equivalent of the above screenshot?

Comment: Have you read the man page?  Looks like -L might be the right option.  It works in a similar way.  Try it.  https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

Comment: I tried with "-L". A->B SSH connection gets established. But C->A->B doesn't work. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: There are other options like -R. That might be what you're after.  Read the manual and try it.

Comment: Got it working with this:

plink -i dummy.ppk -L 0.0.0.0:5678:localhost:1234 account@12.34.56.78

Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

Got the solution. By changing from

```
plink -i dummy.ppk -L *:5678:localhost:1234 account@12.34.56.78
```

to

```
plink -i dummy.ppk -L 0.0.0.0:5678:localhost:1234 account@12.34.56.78
```

it is working as expected.

The difference was this: With the first command, Sysinternals TCPView showed plink.exe opening a connection with local address as 127.0.0.1. With the second command, the local address became 0.0.0.0. I guess this tells plink to accept connections from other hosts.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means all IPv4 addresses on all adapters on the local machine